# npm audit is not working and not listing the description of the dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I am giving the npm audit command but instead of listing the description of the dependencies .It is giving the following output on terminal

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c,
    cache, completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag,
    dist-tags, docs, edit, explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get,
    help, help-search, home, i, info, init, install,
    install-test, issues, it, la, link, list, ll, ln, login,
    logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, prune,
    publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm, root,
    run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, tag, team, test, tst, un, uninstall,
    unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, upgrade, v, verison,
    version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/devendra/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@3.5.2 /usr/share/npm
```

any idea , what i am missing here!

Thank you

Comment: i have tried to upgrade it , but still the result is same, npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: When you run `npm --v` what do you get? You need the latest npm for this to work. It says at the bottom 3.5.2

Comment: its 3.5.2 @adam

Comment: but still not working

Comment: Please help ,it's important

Comment: Dude - update your npm `npm i -g npm` it has to be the latest for this to work. Current version is `6.4.1` you are 3 versions behind

Comment: thanks for help , now it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to upgrade to a newer npm version (see comments).

Just in case someone else experiences the same problem on Ubuntu:

Bash cashes the path of the npm command and you have to clear the bash cache before the new version is used. Detailed explanation:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036278/npm-is-incorrect-version-on-latest-ubuntu-18-04-installation?rq=1